# What types to use in MST for Animated.Value, setInterval, require('image.png')?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I'm using react native with MST and I can't resolve the next question
What types to use in MST for `new Animated.Value(1)`, setInterval, require('image.png')?
Tried `string`, `frozen` that doesn't helped.

```js
import {Animated} from 'react-native';
import {types} from 'mobx-state-tree';

const Worksheet = types
  .model('Worksheet', {
    image: _,
    animated: _,
    timeInterval: _, 
  })

Worksheet.create({
  image: require('image.png'),
  animated: new Animated.Value(1),
  timeInterval: null | setInterval(() => {}, 1000),  
})
```

Need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
const Worksheet = types
  .model('Worksheet', {
    imageFile: types.string,
    animatedValue: 1,
  ).views(self => ({
    get image() {
      return require(self.imageFile);
    },
    get animated() {
      return new Animated.Value(self.animatedValue);
    },
  }).volatile({
    timeInterval: null || setInterval(() => {}, 1000)
  })
```

Not all fields can be types when MST cannot reason about them. That's where [`volatile`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#volatile-state) comes into play. Note that fields inside `volatile` cannot be serialized into snapshots.

I'm not sure what your intent was with `animated` so I put the value as its own type and used a computed getter in the `views` to get the actual thing you want. Perhaps this sparks ideas for you.